# Run UNION with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I needed help with using UNION with a group by.

I wrote the below code you give you an overview of my code. I am basically trying to run this code for over x number of months with UNION.

Everytime I run the below code, SQL SERVER complains "Category" not being in an group by.

I tried adding this to the end of the code:

Group by Name
ORDER BY Name

It still does not work when I am trying to get all the months data at once.

What can I do to make my query run with a UNION clause?

```
SELECT
   '2000' AS Year,
    Name AS Category,
    COUNT(id) AS X
FROM
(          
    (
        Select id, Name
        From dbo.tablea
        where something
        GROUP BY id,name
        HAVING SUM(X)>0
    ) sub

    Union 

    SELECT 
        '1999' AS Year,
        Name AS Category,
        COUNT(id) AS X
    FROM
    (          
        (
            Select id, Name
            From dbo.tablea
            where something
            GROUP BY id,name
            HAVING SUM(X)>0
        ) sub
```

Comment: Your `group by` has no column name.  Fix the code to be `group by name`.

Comment: I am aware of that. I just didnt write it here to save time.

Comment: write your full query so that we will find the solution

Comment: @dataaddicted "I just didnt write it here to save time" Trying to save your time at the expense of your readers' time is no way to get a working answer.

Comment: and format your query in readable form...

Comment: I think other things have been left out "to save time", for instance the sub queries in the initial `FROM` are not closed correctly so I expect your issue could stem from there. Don't save time by screwing about with the structure otherwise people can't help you.

Comment: I have edited and formatted the initial query to show how it is looking at the minute. This query will not run as it is, hopefully it is quite obvious to you from this what might be wrong. It certainly is to me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the first part of the query:

```
SELECT '2000' AS Year, Name AS Category, COUNT(id) AS X
FROM
(
  Select id, Name
  From dbo.tablea
  where ...
  GROUP BY id, Name
  HAVING SUM(X)>0
) sub
```

(I removed one opening parenthesis, that didn't belong there.)

You use an aggregation here (`COUNT(id)`, which is the same as a simple `COUNT(*)` by the way, for an ID should never be null). So what other fields do you select? A literal '2000' which is okay, and Name. But which Name? MAX? MIN? You don't specify it, and this is what the DBMS is telling you. So *either* use an aggregation on Name, such as `MIN(Name)` *or* group by it (by adding `GROUP BY Name` after the "sub" alias), so as to get one line per Name.

Here is the complete query with groups by Name:

```
SELECT '2000' AS Year, Name AS Category, COUNT(id) AS X
FROM
(
  Select id, Name
  From dbo.tablea
  where ...
  GROUP BY id, Name
  HAVING SUM(X)>0
) sub
GROUP BY Name
UNION
SELECT '1999' AS Year, Name AS Category, COUNT(id) AS X
FROM
(
  Select id, Name
  From dbo.tablea
  where ...
  GROUP BY id, Name
  HAVING SUM(X)>0
) sub
GROUP BY Name;
```